# How to make a text field optional in installer?

Tags: nsis

I am new to nsis installer. I have one text field in my ini file. In my installer without entering any data in that field it will not move to other steps. I need to set that text field as a optional. How can i set that field in optional?

Will you help me with it, please?

```
[Settings]
    NumFields=4

    [Field 1]
    Type=Label
    Text="First name"
    Left=0
    Right=54
    Top=67
    Bottom=79

    [Field 2]
    Type=Text
    Left=55
    Right=125
    Top=65
    Bottom=77
    MinLen=1

    [Field 3]
    Type=Label
    Text="Last Name"
    Left=0
    Right=54
    Top=83
    Bottom=95

    [Field 4]
    Type=Text
    Left=55
    Right=125
    Top=113
    Bottom=125
    MinLen=1
```

Make a field 4 is an optional.

Comment: Post the code where you create the custom page (and the leave callback)

Comment: Hi anders i have added my code in above. I am not understanding your question custom page means? I am new to nsis installer.

Comment: No, I want the Install Options code.

Comment: Hi anders i did a small mistake in my code. In my code i have mentioned MinLen=1 for the text field. That's y it is acts as a required. After removing that MinLen=1, now text field is working as a optional field. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Outfile "Optional.exe"
Name "Make Field Optional"
Brandingtext "Created by Kanwar Adnan"

Page Custom Page MakeFieldOptional

Section
sectionEnd

Function .oninit
initpluginsdir
file /oname=$PLUGINSDIR\dlg.ini gmail.ini
FunctionEnd

Function Page
installoptions::dialog "$PLUGINSDIR\dlg.ini"
FunctionEnd

Function MakeFieldOptional
ReadINIStr $0 "$PLUGINSDIR\dlg.ini" "Field 4" "state"
StrCmp $0 "" 0 +3
MessageBox MB_ICONSTOP "Please enter something in field 4"
abort
FunctionEnd
```